# html radio button with an "other" selection that has a text box

Tags: php, html, mysql

When my insert runs it will write the text in the text box but if I choose a radio button selection other than "other" nothing is inserted into the table. 
If I remove the "other"code the radio button selected is written to the table.

here is the code

```
<input type="radio" name="job" value="PHP Programmer">PHP Programmer
<input type="radio" name="job" value="SQL Programmer">SQL Programmer<br>
<input type="radio" name="job">Other <input type="text" name="job" >

<h3>* If yes, check which ISO standard(s) you are accredited?</h3>
<input type="radio" name="iso_standard" value="17020">17020
<input type="radio" name="iso_standard" value="17025">17025

<br />
<input action="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<?php
  if(isset($_POST['job']) && isset($_POST['iso_standard']))
  { 
$job = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['job']);
$iso_standard =mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['iso_standard']);


  $sql="insert into tbl_test_insert(iso_cert, iso_standard)
  values ('$job', '$iso_standard')";

  if(!mysqli_query($db, $sql))
  {
die('Error: ' .mysqli_error($db));
  }
  echo "1 record added";
  }
  else
  {
echo "You didn't choose all the options!
  }

  ?>
```

Comment: Your text input and radio button group shouldn't share the same name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overwriting the value of job with the text input field. It does not mather if it has any value or not.

Please rename your `<input type="text" name="job" >` to for example `otherJob` and you should be fine

**edit:**

change `<input type="radio" name="job">Other <input type="text" name="job" >`

to `<input type="radio" name="job" value="other">Other <input type="text" name="otherJob">`

change `$job = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['job']);`

to

```
  $job = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['job']);
  $otherJob = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['otherJob']);
  if ($job == 'other') {
     $jobField = $otherJob;
  } else {
     $jobField = $job;
  }
```

and change `$sql="insert into tbl_test_insert(iso_cert, iso_standard)
  values ('$job', '$iso_standard')";`

to `$sql="insert into tbl_test_insert(iso_cert, iso_standard)
  values ('$jobField', '$iso_standard')";`

Comment: Thank you, I renamed <input type="text" name="otherJob " > as suggested and now when I type text into the textbox the only thing that is written is "on" to the table  no matter what is typed.

Comment: that is because the other radio button has no value. Please check my edited answer