# Radio button with text field into SQL

Tags: html, sql, radio-button, textfield

I'm making a website where users can insert data into a database and keep track of their medicine intake.
I have a simple form that submits to an SQL database:

```html
<form method='post'>
  <b>Dato:</b> <input type="date" name='date' id='date' value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>" /><br /><br \>
  <b>Tid:</b> <input type="time" name='time' id='time' value="<?php echo " $hour:$minute "; ?>" /><br /><br \>
  <b>Medicin:</b><br /> <input type="radio" name="medicin" value="Medicin1" checked> Medicin1 <br />
  <input type="radio" name="medicin" value="medicin2"> Medicin2 <br />
  <input type="radio" name="medicin" value="other"> Other <input type="text" name="otherMedicin"><br /><br />
  <b>Kommentar:</b><br /><textarea name='comment' id='comment'></textarea><br /> <hr \>
  <input type='submit' value='Send' />
</form>
```

To submit it to the database I found a previous question about the same thing that I follow. Unfortunately I just can't get it to work!
[html radio button with an "other" selection that has a text box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28238977/html-radio-button-with-an-other-selection-that-has-a-text-box)

Here is the important part of my code:

```
$users_date = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['date']);
$users_time = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['time']);
$users_medicin = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['medicin']);
$otherMedicin = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['otherMedicin']);
if ($users_medicin == 'otherMedicin') {
        $medicinField = $otherMedicin;
    } else {
        $medicinField = $users_medicin;
    }

$users_comment = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['comment']);
$query = "
INSERT INTO `myDatabase`.`medi_list` (`id`, `dato`, `tid`, `medicin`, `kommentar`) VALUES (NULL, '$users_date',
    '$users_time', '$medicinField', '$users_comment');";
```

I'm still quite new to SQL so I'd appreciate any help you can throw my way :)

Comment: You say that it "don't work", but you didn't say why or what don't work. You get an error message? (in that case what message do you get) You don't get expected results? (in that case what are you getting now)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see some basic problems in your code:

When you are populating the field "$otherMedicin", you are using $db instead of $con like the other statements.

$_POST[medicin] is NEVER going to be "otherMedicin", because that is the name of your text input field, not the radio button name. You should have this as your conditional:

```
if ($users_medicin == 'other') {
```

That should help a bit.

Comment: Thank you so much! This was exactly what I needed to get it done!
I had been looking so much at it that I couldn't see the mistakes.